TLS setup failed: failed to load certificate file "/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.se/fullchain.pem": (null)
I have a client with ssl=require
I have PgBouncer pgbouncer.ini
# SSL/TLS configuration for client connections
client_tls_sslmode = require
client_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.se/privkey.pem
client_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.se/fullchain.pem     

And i get this error when starting the service:
TLS setup failed: failed to load certificate file "/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.se/fullchain.pem": (null)

chmod, owner (postgres:postgres) and paths is OK
Any hint what is wrong?
